# Can we said "last morning"?

Tags: grammar, usage, time, time-reference

Normally we'll use `last night` when we're talking about yesterday's night, but how about yesterday's morning? Why can't we use `last morning` so as afternoon? Just like `last weekend`, `last Friday`, last meant the nearest time in the past. Then why can't we call yesterday's morning as `last morning`?

Comment: It is just not idiomatic. These are:  yesterday afternoon or yesterday morning. But,f for example: The last morning of the event, we met for coffee. You can't say última mañana for yesterday morning in Spanish either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think that saying "*last morning*" is sensible?

"*Last morning*" mathematically means "*this morning*". 
How can "*last morning*" be yesterday's morning?

If "*yesterday's morning*" is "*last morning*", how about "*this morning*" ?

Didn't it exist?

Comment: I don't think this  is about being "sensible". It also can make sense in some contexts. **The last morning they saw him was Sunday.**

Comment: I'd say: "The last day they saw him was Sunday", still not "the last morning".

Comment: That would be wrong if they had been discussing the mornings when they saw him and not the afternoons or evenings. The last night, the  last morning and the last night [something happened or of some event] is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing this as anything but a restatement of the question. Monday night we refer to Monday morning as "this" morning but Sunday night as "last" night. Isn't that just idiomatic, with at least equal reason to recommend "last" in each case?

Comment: It's dawning on me. The question was whether, on Monday night, we can refer to Sunday morning (not Monday morning) as "last" morning.

Answer (score 1):

We *don't* say "last morning". Instead we say "yesterday morning". Similarly we say "yesterday afternoon".

Perhaps the reason for this is that "last morning" could refer to the morning of today, if you use it in the afternoon. Language isn't logical, but this seems reasonable.

There are a few times when you might see these words together:

> On the last morning of my vacation, I stood by the pool, and thought about what a great time I'd had.

But that doesn't mean "the previous morning".